# Multiple Between Statements

Tags: sql, sum, between

I'm a student developer currently taking a SQL course. I'm currently trying to retrieve the sum of several groups of rows from a table. I'm very new to SQL development and I'm not too sure what the problem is in the following scenario. I have a large table of which I want to select specific rows from and then add the balance column.

The following will not display any data in the results and I'm not too sure why. I have a hunch that the between statement can only be used once per table but maybe I'm wrong?

```
Select Description, SUM(Balance) AS Total_Balance
FROM Chart_Of_Accounts
WHERE (Account BETWEEN ('400401') AND ('400407')) 
AND (Account BETWEEN ('440094') AND ('440100')) 
AND (Account BETWEEN ('450094') AND ('450100'))
GROUP BY Description, Balance
```

***Edit 10.1.2012*** As requested by (Richard aka cyberkiwi)

**What I Have**

```
Set 1
|Account        |Description         |Balance
|4004xx         |Red Wine            |$2361.23
|4004xx         |White Wine          |$3620.23
|4004xx         |Rice Wine           |$1223.23

Set 2
|Account        |Description         |Balance
|4400xx         |Red Wine            |$4361.23
|4400xx         |White Wine          |$3260.23
|4400xx         |Rice Wine           |$223.23

Set 3
|Account        |Description         |Balance
|4500xx         |Red Wine            |$1361.23
|4500xx         |White Wine          |$1620.23
|4500xx         |Rice Wine           |$1223.23
```

**Result I'm Trying to Achieve**

```
Total
|Description         |Total_Balance
|Red Wine            |$8083.69
|White Wine          |$8500.69
|Rice Wine           |$2669.69
```

thank you for reading my post! I am also open to any advice in SQL development and any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use ORs instead of ANDs!
What you mean to express is, give me results where it is between A and B, `or` it is between C and D etc.

```
  SELECT Description, SUM(Balance) AS Total_Balance
    FROM Chart_Of_Accounts
   WHERE (Account BETWEEN '400401' AND '400407') 
      OR (Account BETWEEN '440094' AND '440100') 
      OR (Account BETWEEN '450094' AND '450100')
GROUP BY Description
```

I dropped the extraneous brackets, but you could even drop the remaining ones becaues the ORs get processed after the ANDs.  See: [SQL Server Operator Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx)

Comment: I understand what your saying but what I really want is to do is combine(SUM) the balance of these records (rows) using the account number between A - D AND H-S AND U-X. When using OR I only get A-D due to its sequential occurrence. Thanks for your quick answer! I'm sorry about my vernacular here I'm still learning.

Comment: Can you edit the question with some sample results? Do you want to group by description or account? Do you want 3 rows, one for each group A-d, H-S, U-X, which would mean grouping by account, not description?

Comment: Of course! I will happily edit my question for you! In this table that I am querying I only have four columns. Accounts (holds account numbers), Description (holds product name), Short Description (holds account type), and Balance (holds a money value). What I'm trying to do is grab several accounts from this table and add their balances together. I was trying to use the group by function to group the same products together as each location has the same 6 products in these accounts.

Answer (score 2):

If your name starts with a W, can you letter be between A-D **and** F-M **and** U-Z?  Of course not.

However, it CAN be between A-D **or** F-M **or** U-Z.

Same thing applies with the Account number.

Answer (score 0):

I think part of your problem (other than the use of AND where it should be OR, as RichardTheKiwi so kindly pointed out) is that you are grouping by both Description and Balance. You should only be grouping by Description since you are trying to sum the balances for each description. You would group by balance if you were interested in each unique value for Balance and in aggregate functions (SUM(), AVG(), STDEV(), ...) on other fields for each unique Balance.